# Update Categories

Tags: forms, laravel

I am pretty close to a solution but am stuck. I have a category page where the category is created and deleted on the same page. I am adding a edit function, edit link, and making it to where the user can edit the category on the same page instead of creating another static page and repeating the same code.

Here is my controller function for update

```
public function postEdit() {
    $category = Category::find(Input::get('id'));

    if ($category) {
        $category->update();
        return Redirect::to('admin/categories/index')
        ->with('message', 'Category Updated');
    }

    return Redirect::to('admin/categories/index')
        ->with('message', 'Something went wrong, please try again');
}
```

Here is the category page where a user can view, create, edit, and delete the categories listed I am trying to have a conditional that states to show create form as default and only show edit form when edit button is clicked.

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')

<div id="admin">

    <h1>Categories Admin Panel</h1><hr>

    <p>Here you can view, delete, create, and edit new categories.</p>

    <h2>Categories</h2><hr>

    <ul>
        @foreach($categories as $category)
            <li>
                {{ $category->name }} - 
                {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/categories/destroy', 'class'=>'form-inline')) }}
                {{ Form::hidden('id', $category->id) }}
                {{ Form::submit('delete') }}
                {{ Form::close() }}

                {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/categories/edit', 'class'=>'form-inline'))}}
                {{ Form::hidden('id', $category->id) }}
                {{ Form::submit('edit') }}
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>

    <h2>Create New Category</h2><hr>

    @if($errors->has())
    <div id="form-errors">
        <p>The following errors have occurred:</p>

        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end form-errors -->
    @endif
    <php
    if(isset(url=>'admin/categories/destroy')) {
        {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/categories/create')) }}
        <p>
            {{ Form::label('name') }}
            {{ Form::text('name') }}
        </p>
        {{ Form::submit('Create Category', array('class'=>'secondary-cart-btn')) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}

    }else{

        {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/categories/edit')) }}
        <p>
            {{ Form::label('name') }}
            {{ Form::text('name') }}
        </p>
        {{ Form::submit('Create Category', array('class'=>'secondary-cart-btn')) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}

    }
?>

</div><!-- end admin -->

@stop
```

Please give me an example of how I can accomplish this on the same view page. I know I somehow have to pass in a variable as the value in the form to fill the category selected.
Thank you for the help.

By the way, if you are a moderator and close my question, I will block my IP address, throw a million IP addresses in the network, and just sign up again and again and again with a temp email.

I tried doing a javascript onclick event and here is my results. I cannot get it to work.

Button for link

```
 {{ HTML::Link('#', 'edit', array('class'=>'form-inline', 'id'=>'button',      'onclick'=>'showEditForm(this)'))}}
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function showEditForm(id) { 
id.innerHTML="


{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/categories/edit')) }}
    <p>
        {{ Form::hidden('id', $category->id) }}
        {{ Form::label('name') }}
        {{ Form::text('name') }}
    </p>
    {{ Form::submit('Edit Category', array('class'=>'secondary-cart-btn')) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}

";

}
</script>
```

Comment: Create an edit button and attach an `onclick` event handler with JavaScript to it, and the event handler should show the edit form.

Comment: That is a good idea, but because Javascript could be disabled and not active on all browsers is there a way to do it with php and laravel.

Comment: Pass in a parameter in the URL, and in your view check if that parameter exists. If it does, show the edit form, otherwise, don't. When the first time the user loads the page, you can have a link that basically points to that same page, but with the parameter appended as a query string in the `href` attribute. They'd then click it to show the edit form.

Comment: `By the way, if you are a moderator and close my question, I will block my IP address, throw a million IP addresses in the network, and just sign up again and again and again with a temp email.` -1 for this.

Comment: I mostly understand the parameter by looking at this [site](http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php) However, what would the parameter be in my situation? I am sorry I am tired currently.

Comment: @itachi I would rather not use this site because of the close minded moderators who are button happy, but sometimes I have to. The community on stackoverflow is strong, committed, and help others out. It is some moderators though who are just looking to climb the ranks that make me turn my head. However, this is a whole different topic.

Answer (score 0):

actually your question is perfectly fine, i gave it a -1 due to the rant. none the less, this question really deserves an answer.

let's sum up your problem. you have 3 main tasks.

- create
- edit
- delete

**For Create**:

pretty easy. use a 2 column layout. on the side bar, show the form to create category. then use ajax to submit. e.g.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('submit','#writeCategory', function(e){

                var f = $(this);
                e.preventDefault();
                var d = f.serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type        :       POST,
                    url         :       //your url,
                    data        :       d
                }).done(function(data){
                    alert('submitted');
                    //you can also prepend/append the submitted data after successful submission
                }).fail(function(x,h,r){
                    alert('error occured')
                });                
    });
});
```

**For Edit:**

for editing, you can use [**Xeditable**](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html). the page has all demo, docs in the site.

**For delete:**

i'l mention a very simplified approach. using `data-` attribute. if you want to delete a category, probably you will need only the id.

suppose you are looping to show all the categories. while doing so, store the id in a say, `data-id` attribute. and write a delete link for each category.

e.g. a delete link for single category entity may look like following:

`<a href="#" class="delete" data-id={{$i->id}}>delete</a>`

rest is easy. just use ajax and delete the link. e.g.

```
$(function(){
        $('.delete').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var a = $(this);            
            var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
            if (answer)
            {
                
                    $.ajax({
                        type        :     'post',
                        url         :       //your url,
                        data        :       {id:a.attr('data-id')}  
                    }).done(function(data){
                        alert('deleted');
                    }).fail(function(x,h,r){
                        alert('error occured');
                    });
            }

        });
    });
```

you can also modify it. e.g. after deletion, if you are showing the categories in a tabular manner, you can slide up the row (which contains the specified catgory information) hinting that, that category has been deleted.

*Addition*

**For View:**

there are loads of javascript model window plugins. just select one and through ajax, show the details.

All 4 tasks, done in one place.

N.B. here i have used *jQuery* just for convenience. if you want plain javascript, you can write it that way too....

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I decided to just grab the category id as the products id and pass the variable.